# How to understand this proof about the remainder of a sum of integers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

- In an arithmetic expression with +,* and mod the modulo operator is the one with the least priority.
- Lemme M: $\forall x,y \in N, \forall b \in N^*$

We want to prove this:

(x+y)mod b = ( (x mod b) + (y mod b) ) mod b

**Proof**: $x = k*b + r, r<b$ and $y= k'*b+r',r'<b$ provided by the theorem of unicity of quotient and remainders.

Now we have, x+y mod b = ((k+k')*b + r + r')mod b.

In the same way, $r+r' = k''*b + r$,  r'' < b ( i.e. r'' = r + r' mod b ) and therefore $x+y = ( k + k'+ k'')*b + r''$ , by the theorem of unicity, x + y mod b = r'' = r + r' mod b which is what we wanted to demonstrate.

I do not understand where does this $r+r' = k''*b + r$ comes from?

I also have trouble understanding where this $x+y = ( k + k'+ k'')*b + r''$ comes from?

How does those equations fit in the big picture?

Comment: Thinking in terms of remainders is not the way to go. $x=y\bmod b$ means $x-y$ is a multiple of $b$. Then the result is obvious. Computer science often uses $x\bmod b$ to mean the remainder of $x$ when divided by $b$. But the math term **doesn't** mean the remainder. Stricly $x\bmod b$ means nothing. $\bmod p$ is a binary relation. Indeed it is occasionally written $=_p$

Comment: That proof is full of typos and is ... well... enough typos that I'd call it garbage.

Comment: The main idea is that if $x=kb + r$ and $y=k'b + r'$ then $x+y = (k+k')b + (r+r')$.  Now if $r+r' < b$ then $r+r'$, which is the sum of the remainders,  is the remainder of $x+y$.  And if $b \le r+r' < 2b$ then the remainder of $r+r'$ is $r+r'-b$ and the remainder of $x + y$ is $r+r'-b$ also.  .... but you now.... who gives a flying fig about the *smallest* remainder?  All that really matters is if the $x$ and $x'$, and $y$ and $y'$ differ by a multiple of $b$.  Then $x+y$ and $x'+y'$ will differ by a multiple of $b$.

Comment: @almagest I'm okay with "thinking in terms of remainders" provided it's "have the same remainder" or "two numbers are equivalent and essentially the same thing if they have the same remainder or one is some multiple of $b$ more than the other".  But thinking of operations so that you add to numbers and then *don't* consider its equivalence is where I think you get into trouble... me... peteto, peteto...

Comment: Oh, I see.  this proof is defining $((x\mod b)+(y\mod b))\mod b= r"$ So $(x\mod b) + (y\mod b) = k"b + r"$.  And as $x\mod b = r$ and $y\mod b = r'$ we have $r + r' = k"b +r"$.  Then they actually add $x + y$ to *calculate* $(x+y)\mod b$.  ... My instinct is to do the opposite.  To *define* $(x+y)\mod b$ and *calculate* $(r+r')\mod b$.  But the both are the same in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\% b= r$  (For various reasons I *refuse* to let my fingers type "$x\mod b = r$")

Let $y\%b = r'$  and $(x+y) \%b = r"$.

That means $r < b; r' < b; r" < b$ and thhere are $k,k', k"$ so that

$x = kb + r; y = k'b + r'$ and $x+y = k"b + r"$.

That means $x+y = (kb+r) + (k'b+r') = (k+k')b + (r+r') = k"b + r"$

That mean $(r+r') =k"b- (k+k')b +r" =  (k"-k-k')b + r"$ and $r" < b$.  So $(r+r')\% b = r"$.

[We can show that $k" - k -k'$ is either equal to $0$ ir $r+r' < b$ or is equal to $1$ if $b\le r+r'< 2b$, but that's not important.]

And so $(r+r')\% b = ((x\%b)+(y\%b))\%b = (x+y)\% b$.

.....

But really, eventually you will need to stop caring about *smallest* remainders, and start caring about whether the differences between numbers is a multiple of $b$.

The equivalent result would be if you use the notation

$x \equiv r \pmod b$  (Notice that is *NOT* an equal sign) to mean that the difference between $x$ and $r$ is a multiple of $ b$, or in other words $x = kb + r$ for some $k$ (and we don't give flying fig about whether $r < b$..... that's ... irrelevant)

Then this statement is equivalent to: if $x \equiv r\pmod b$ and $y \equiv r'\pmod b$ than $x + y \equiv r+r' \pmod b$.

And proof:  $x= kb + r$ for some $k$.  And $y = k'b +r'$ for some $k'$.  So $x + y = b(k+k') + (r+')$ and as $b(k+k')$ is a multiple of $b$ that means $x+y \equiv r+r' \pmod b$.